# How to use the response PHP variables in a XHR call?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have two pages say, page1.php and page2.php. In page1.php I have a button, when clicked it makes XHR call to page2.php and shows the response in a defined divison i.e. "print" in page1.

Code for page1.php

```
<html>
    <button type="button" onclick="randomFunction()">Request data</button>
    <div id="print"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function randomFunction()
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
          document.getElementById("print").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","page2.php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Code for page2.php

```
<?php
$a = "apple";
$b = "banana";
echo $a;
echo $b;
?>
```

Output I am getting now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDdaa.jpg

I want to manipulate with the response I'm getting from page2. As in I want to show "apple" in red and "banana" in blue on page1.php

How do I do that?

Comment: Why aren't you `echo`ing with CSS classes from `page2.php`? For example: `echo '<span class="red-apple">'.$a.'</span>';`

Comment: I can do that. But according to the real situation, I am not allowed to add css in page2.php. I have to manipulate in page1.php.

Comment: Could you send back JSON and then you could get different values easily. And then add styling in `page1.php`.

Comment: How do I catch the JSON values? 
Suppose, I change my page2.php to `echo json_encode($a . $b);`

Answer (score 2):

Send back JSON from `page2.php` and then add your custom HTML with that data to `page1.php`.

**page1.php**

```
<html>
    <button type="button" onclick="randomFunction()">Request data</button>
    <div id="print"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function randomFunction()
        {
          var xmlhttp;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
              var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
              var html = '<span class="apple">'+data.a+'</span><span class="banana">'+data.b+'</span>';

              document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = html;
            }
          }

          xmlhttp.open("POST","page2.php",true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
  $a = "apple";
  $b = "banana";

  echo json_encode( array( 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b ) );
?>
```

Now you could style these `span`s like you want. Of course you can edit the HTML structure to your desire.

**Only PHP**

**page1.php**

```
<html>
    <a href="?showData=1">Request data</a>
    <div id="print">
        <?php
        // Show data only, if our link was clicked
        if( $_GET['showData'] == 1 ){
            // Get page2.php
            require_once('page2.php');

            echo '<span class="apple">'.$a.'</span><span class="banana">'.$b.'</span>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
  $a = "apple";
  $b = "banana";
?>
```

Comment: Can I use this response data in PHP instead of in JS?

Comment: I have added PHP example to my post. But you can't use JS variable in PHP anymore. PHP execution is ended before JS is starting. This would work only if you make another AJAX request, send your received JSON to it and response with HTML. But this is not necessary, since you could respond with HTML already in `page2.php`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use the response data in PHP. Since, there will be a lot of manipulation in design. How to do that?

Comment: You can't use this data directly in PHP anymore. PHP has ended it's execution. Like I said, only way is to send your response back with new AJAX request and use data there. After that, respond with manipulated design. This is the only way. Why won't you make the design in `page1.php` and get data for it by making AJAX request. Then just add it to correct places.

Comment: Is my answer enough for you?